# Sorting a graph's adjacency matrix by the *objectively* best edges for the TSP

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, graph-theory, sorting

Is there a way that I can take an adjacency matrix and sort the edges in terms of which edges are objectively most valuable (a best pick) for a TSP circuit?

You cannot do it via sorting by lowest weight, because a row of [5, 19, 22, 28, 300] would all be sorted before [2000, 9000, 50000, 51000, 52000], even though the 2000 is much more valuable for your path than any of the choices are in the other row.

I tried normalizing the rows to unit length, which gives a more accurate picture of each edge's value in terms of efficiency.  It is still often incorrect, though, and will end up finding a path without having all of the true best edges in it's collection.

I think the key involves sorting by the difference from one element to the next of the same row, so you get value in terms of how much you lose by moving on to the nextedge.

Does anyone know anything about this?

Comment: Solving TSP is known to be NP-hard, so unless P=NP, any way of measuring which edges are "objectively best" is either going to be a heuristic (and sometimes wrong) or else will take a very long time to run on large instances.

Comment: Well, I don't mean sorting such that the n best would make up a list of size n.  I mean, sorting such that if you incrementally increase the size of your set by 1, the moment your set contains a hamiltonian cycle it would also contain the edges that comprise the best path.  so yeah, that set might be huge and then the issue from there would be finding the best path within it.

Comment: @TravisBlack Are you sure that this is what you want? Suppose that you have a vertex of degree two. Then put its two incident edges at the very end and the rest ealier, according to an arbitrary permutation. This sequence has your desired property, but it does not give you any information.

Comment: I am not sure I understand, what you are saying.  When you say, "the very end", you mean the very end of what?  Of a minimal list of size n, of our sorted edges, that can contain a hamiltonian cycle?

If that is what you are saying, then yes, this is what I want.